# Symfony: Warning: session_start(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed

Tags: php, symfony, session

Symfony gives me an error when I try to switch users (impersonate) using `_switch_user`. It started happening probably after changing sessions table name. Everything else works fine (setting and getting data from session without impersonating).

> Warning: session_start(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed

Precise error from logs

> [2020-05-21 11:28:37] php.WARNING: Warning: session_start(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Warning: session_start(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed at /app/my_app/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php:151)"} []

Precise line which triggers an error (`\src\EventListener\MyListener.php`)

```
public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event) {
   $request = $event->getRequest();
   $request->getSession()->set('hash', $_ENV['HASH']);
}
```

My session handler config (`config\services.yml`)

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler:
        public: false
        arguments:
            - 'mysql:host=%env(DATABASE_HOST)%;dbname=%env(DATABASE_NAME)%'
            - { db_table: 'my_sessions', db_username: '%env(DATABASE_USER)%', db_password: '%env(DATABASE_PASSWORD)%', lock_mode: 0 }
```

My session config (`config\packages\framework.yml`)

```
session:
        handler_id: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
        cookie_samesite: 'none'
        cookie_secure: true
        cookie_httponly: true
        gc_probability: 0
```

I am using

- Symfony 4.4.2
- PHP 7.2
- "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.1.2"

Answer (score 3):

I think I encountered today the same problem as you. I'm working with Symfony 5, but it is also the same for Symfony 4. The problem was because my `User` had a `ManytoMany` relation and in some case, the full object, with all the children entities was serialized and stored in session. On `PdoSessionHandler` the data is stored in a `BLOB` field which is limited to 64Kb and my serialized object was getting over 100Kb !

**Steps to verify**

When your page crashes in dev mode, it is on the redirect after your post. Go on the debug bar, on the bottom left, where it is written `500` and open the menu. You should see : `Redirect from POST @route (profile)`. **profile** is a link so click on it. In the profiler go on **Request/Response** > ** session **. There you should see, in **Session Attributes** a key starting with `_security_` and the name of your firewall (mine was `admin`, so it was `_security_admin` ). There you should see the data stored, if it exceeds 64K, that's it!

**Steps to fix**

You have to implement the `Serializable` interface in your user entity as stated here : https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security/entity_provider.html (this also works in SF 5). This will make the serialized object much lighter!

**Be careful**

Changing serialization may have impact on other features in your site so be careful of side effects. Also I had a problem because I have a custom `getUsername()` and this method is used for user verification, so be aware that your custom methods may have an impact on user verification!